# Travelling from Poland to Canada with temporary passport

Tags: visas, passports, canada, poland

I am travelling to Canada next week. My girlfriend would like to go to with me, yet she does not have the passport. The only option left for her on such a short notice is getting the temporary passport (non-biometric).

We are Polish citizens and would like to know whether one can enter Canada with temporary passport and is visa needed in such circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Polish temporary passport to travel to Canada.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in relevant part:

> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of Poland with a temporary passport.

You still need to get an [electronic travel authorization](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta.html) (eTA) before traveling though.

> Visa required, except for Nationals of Poland with an
> Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA). They are visa exempt
> for a maximum stay of 6 months.

You'll need the passport number to apply for the eTA, so you should obtain it as soon as possible.